# Convert a font into monospaced version

Tags: fonts, monospace

I'm using DotMatrix font for my powerscan simulator, but I would need a monospaced version of that which is not available. Is there any chance to convert a font into a monospaced one? or better, there's a dotmatrix looking like mono font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a monospaced DotMatrix
https://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/DotMatrix.font